# Method setDate() of Mobiscroll jQuery Plugin loses format

Tags: datetime, mobiscroll, preset

setDate() works but loses previously set format.

```
var initialDate = new Date(1984,11,19);
$('#mydate').scroller({
    preset: 'date',
    dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'        
});
$('#mydate').scroller('setDate', initialDate, true);
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

No need to call setdate like that.
If you simply passe the date directly on input value, it works pretty well